# inconvertiable type,cannot cast,Fragment

Tags: android

```
 private void changeCity(String city)
{
 WeatherFragment wf =(WeatherFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container); 
wf.changeCity(city); 
}
```

This is my error:

> Inconvertible type; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'to'.
>   Can you give me a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can show " import "  in your app?

I thinks at WeatherFragment extend Fragment. You must

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```